# How do you compile flex in Visual Studio 2005/2008?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005, flex-lexer

I can't figure this one out.  I can download a win32 binary of flex 2.5.4a from gnuwin32, but I'd like to build the latest version (2.5.35) using Visual Studio 2005.  I suppose I could build in in cygwin, but where is the fun in that?

Comment: It might help if you elaborated a little on how far you've made it.

Comment: i gave up. i like to build my own tools, but flex can't be built in vs2005 without a lot of modifications. i could build it in cygwin. if someone has found the secret sauce for building flex in vs200x, i'd love to know what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since nobody provided a satisfactory answer to my question, i am posting my final solution here.

i was unable to find a way to build flex in vs 2005 or vs 2008.  instead, i am using the flex that is distributed with cygwin, which is pretty recent.  in order to save myself the hassle of installing cygwin on every machine that i need to use flex on, i just saved off the dependencies: cygwin1.dll and cygintl-8.dll.

there is only one caveat - cygwin's flex also depends on m4, though you won't see it on the dependency walker.  it needs to be in the path, which makes it a pain.  you can use cygwin's m4.exe, but it depends on cygwin1.dll also, which will need to be in the path for m4 to execute.

even so, i just check all of those files into my svn under a tools folder and then whenever i need to develop on another machine, get my code and flex with svn, copy m4.exe and cygwin1.dll to the windows\system32 folder, and i'm in business.

Answer (score 2):

Note that Flex is seriously out-of-date on Windows when it comes to generating C++ scanners. Recent Flex versions which are able to generate ISO C++ scanners do not support Win32 (MinGW or VS), so you're probably better of trying to generate a C scanner and call it from C++.

Answer (score 1):

You can also download the MINGW (Minimalist GNU for Windows) build of flex 2.5.35 at [sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS%20flex/).  This build may not be entirely self-contained; the release notes suggest that certain components of [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS) (Minimal SYSytem) are required.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't want to try the Spirit framework from Boost?