# When will a newer version of flex for windows be available?

Tags: flex-lexer, gnuwin32

I'm using [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex) (lexical analyzer, not Adobe Flex) on a project. However, I want to be able to compile on Windows platforms as well, but the [Windows version](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/flex.htm)'s newest version is only 2.5.4a, so it won't compile my file for version 2.5.35. And no, I can't downgrade to the highest supported Windows version.

Anyone know about plans to upgrade the windows version, or have a suggestion to compile on windows anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ask on the mailing list, or *get involved* in the Flex project yourself. I think the code-base for Flex has remained static for a while, but I don't know who maintains the Windows port. In the interim...

I would recommend **including the produced source** in your project.

1. Generate the lexer on a Linux system to produce your lex.c/lex.h files (or whatever)
2. Include those files in your Win32 C source before you build

If you don't have direct access to a Linux system, a virtual machine might be a good idea. The Flex source *should* be complaint to some C standard that builds on Windows, but most of the POSIX differences can be altered to use Win32 API fairly easily.

Maybe distribute as:

```
/src/source_files.c
/src/lex.l
/src/win32_lex/lex.c
```

This way systems *with* a modern flex can generate the source from the lex file, and Windows systems compiling the source can use the complementary pre-processed C files.

Short of using some user-space POSIX (Cygwin or whatever).

A little bit of tweaking required, but *isn't that portability for you*!

Comment: +1, personally I just use Cygwin when the .lex/.y files change.

Comment: Could you explain how to use Cygwin to compile using the Linux version of Flex? I did try to use it for this project, but didn't get very far.

Comment: How to compile the Flex source itself, or generate the C files from Flex? There *should* be a cygwin version of Flex already

Answer (score 1):

Windows builds of flex 2.5.35 **do** exist, but unfortunately they are not self contained.  You can download the MINGW build [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS%20flex/), and the Cygwin build [here](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/misc/winflex/); see [also another stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226820/how-do-you-compile-gnu-flex-in-visual-studio-2005-2008).  Each build requires that its respective (MINGW or Cygwin) kernel be installed.